# How to create a vector with 0 in certain rows and 1 in any other rows?

Tags: r

Say I have 100 numerical values in a column. I want to create a vector that returns 0 when the numerical value of an entry is greater than or equal to 2, and returns 1 if the numeric value is less than 2. I suppose it's trivial but still don't know how...

Comment: `as.integer(df$column_name < 2)`

Comment: Or `ifelse(df$column_name < 2, 1, 0)`